# Problem making a CRUD in a Database with Symfony 7

Tags: php, symfony, orm, crud, entities

Using this database:

[image]

I have to make a CRUD in these tables. I made the Entities, deleting the "id" attribute, given that the tables from the database already have their own Primary Key.

An example: Entity Zonas:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ZonasRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ZonasRepository::class)]
class Zonas
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $cod_zona = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $nombre_zona = null;

    public function getCodZona(): ?int
    {
        return $this->cod_zona;
    }

    public function setCodZona(int $cod_zona): static
    {
        $this->cod_zona = $cod_zona;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNombreZona(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nombre_zona;
    }

    public function setNombreZona(string $nombre_zona): static
    {
        $this->nombre_zona = $nombre_zona;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I used the command make:crud to create a CRUD on the tables, but I don't know how to generate new numbers of the Primary Keys within Symfony. For example: when I create a new Zone. I got this exception:

> ## An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Obviously, this is because the cod_zona attribute isn't autogenerated. How can I do this?

I created a crud, I didn't make any doctrine migrations because the database was already defined (FK and PK included). I need to create these new codes when I create a new instance:
ZONAS: The max zona number +1.

EQUIPO: Is a integer composed by the number of the zone and another number starting by 1. If you got 4 EQUIPO in a zone, the next EQUIPO you create is 15 (ZONA 1, EQUIPO 5).

JUGADORES: I a integer composed by the number of the EQUIPO and another number starting by 1 (the same way as EQUIPO with ZONAS).

PARTIDOS: The same as ZONAS: the max PARTIDOS +1.

Comment: What you are looking for is probably a customIdGenerator -> https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-bundle/en/2.11/custom-id-generators.html